# Can an application level style reference a UserControl resource?

Tags: wpf

In my WPF application I created a resource of type SolidColorBrush and a button style which uses this resource as a background.
In my UserControl I override the color resource with the same name but a different color.
Can I create it in a way that a button in that UserControl will use the application Style but with the color defined in the UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here is a little bit against the idea of resources in WPF as you try to mix up the top-down nature of resource definitions. So even if you get it to work, it will lead to untypical behavior, making it hard for the next person working on the code (or the future-you) to understand what's going on.

I would suggest to do the following to get exactly the behavior you want, still keeping things in order:

Suppose your app level resource like this:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColor" Color="Blue" />

<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
    ... (other setters)
</Style>
```

If you want to override the `Foreground` with a local brush, do this explicitly when using the TextBlock (might be your UserControl as well) and use `BasedOn` to inherit everything else from the app level style:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyOverridingColor" Color="Red" />

<Style x:Key="OverridingTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyOverridingColor}" />
</Style>
```

I would suggest to use a different name for the second color (`MyOverridingColor` in the example above) to make clear that it is a different color.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to have a button style and use it in several UserControls, but the colors in that style should be dependent on on the UserControl that contains UserControls that use this style.
For example:
The app has a button style called "PrimaryButtonStyle"
it is used in Controls "UC1", "UC2", "UC3"
UC1, 2 and 3 go into a one of 2 ContentControl.
I want it defined in a way that the button looks the same on all controls but the colors are dependent on the ContentControl but will also look good in the designer